# Visualforce Email Template apex:facet not showing in result

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, datatable, vf-email-template

I am having an issue wherein the apex:facet header for my apex data table is not showing up in the result. I am fairly certain this is due to be adding a filter for the record type in the column. However, since I need both functionality, is there any workaround for this to have the header re-appear?

```
         <apex:dataTable value="{!relatedTo.Cases__r}" var="c" id="caseTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" border="solid" cellpadding="5px">
            <apex:column rendered="{!if(claim.recordTypeID == '01224000000EpzRAAS','true','false')}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Case Number</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column rendered="{!if(claim.recordTypeID == '01224000000EpzRAAS','true','false')}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Case Type</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!c.Type}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column rendered="{!if(claim.recordTypeID == '01224000000EpzRAAS','true','false')}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Follow up Date</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,Date,dd/MM/yy}"><apex:param value="{!c.Follow_up__c}" /></apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: What is `claim`? You define a var `c`, but there's no `claim` here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header to appear but not the value, you can place the filter at the `apex:outputText` instead:

```xml
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">Case Number</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!c.CaseNumber}" rendered="{!claim.recordTypeID == '01224000000EpzRAAS'}"/>
</apex:column>
```

Tip: `rendered` attribute expects a Boolean value, conditional logic returns a Boolean, hence no IF function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same issue, try to use a getter, setter variable instead of directly adding if condition on the apex:column tag, and assign the value to the variable from the controller. The same I did and it worked.

Example,

```
<apex:column rendered="{!showColumn}"> 
     <apex:facet name="header">I am Column Header</apex:facet> 
     <apex:outputText value="Hii.. Welcome"/> 
</apex:column>
```